# Is this Hasse Diagrams correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the following problem:

Given set A={a,b,c,d,e}
and R={(a,a),(a,c),(a,d),(a,e),(b,b),(b,c),(b,d),(b,e),(c,c),(c,d),(c,e),(d,d),(e,e)}

This might be easy but I'm trying to draw the Hasse Diagram for this problem but don´t fully understand how to, as 'a' and 'b' don't connect.

Is this diagram correct?

[Hasse Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WNux.png)

Comment: No.  ac, bc,ce, cd.